# Return a result of type error in a Method

Tags: 2d, processing, collision

Im working on the collision detection in my 2D Processing 2.2.1 game. Basically what I did was write a class which creates a box by defining the coordinates of its endpoints and which has a method to check if two of these boxes overlap. I did this by introducing a boolean which is set to true as soon two of these boxes overlap. Then basically implementing a get method which creates these boxes, I run into a return a result of type error. It says that the method is not returning the correct type of Box1. I dont really understand since the box which I am returning does fit the constructor. I am pretty sure it is due to the fact that the objects colliding are in an array which generates more and more objects with time, but I sadly do not know how I would have to change my Collider ( Box1) class.

here is the code im getting the error on:

```
//returning collider info
public Box1 getBox1() {
     for (int i =frameCount/600; i >0; i--) {
     return new Box1( block[i].x - Blockpic.width/2, block[i].y-Blockpic.height/2,      block[i].x+Blockpic.height/2, block[i].y+Blockpic.height/2);
 }
```

}

this is my collider (Box1) class:

```
public class Box1 {
    float x1, x2;
    float y1, y2;

    Box1( float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2 ) {
    this.x1 = x1;
    this.y1 = y1;

    this.x2 = x2;
    this.y2 = y2;
 }

 boolean isOverlap( Box1 b ) {
 if ((( x1 <= b.x1 && b.x1 <= x2 ) || ( x1 <= b.x2 && b.x2 <= x2 ))
 && (( y1 <= b.y1 && b.y1 <= y2 ) || ( y1 <= b.y2 && b.y2 <= y2 ))) {
    return true;
 }
    return false;
 }
}
```

just for complete info my spawning objects class ( where the error is situated) :

```
public class Blockfield {
    private int Blockcount;
    private PImage Blockpic;
    private Block block[];

  //Constructor
  public Blockfield (int Blockcount) {
    this.Blockcount = Blockcount; 
    Blockpic = loadImage("block2.png");
    //new array
    block = new Block [Blockcount];
    for ( int i=0; i < Blockcount; i++) {
      block[i] = new Block( width+Blockpic.width, random (height),7);
    }
  }


  //Draw method for this class


  public void draw () {
   for (int i =frameCount/600; i >0; i--) {
     pushMatrix();
      translate ( block[i].x,block[i].y );
      image ( Blockpic, block[i].x, block[i].y);
      popMatrix();
    }
  }

   public void update() {
     for (int i =frameCount/600; i >0; i--) {
     //moves blocks right to left
      block[i].x -=(6 * (frameCount/200));
      //spawns block when they leave the screen
      if (block[i].x < 0 - Blockpic.width) {
        block[i] = new Block( width+Blockpic.width, random (height),7);
      }
     }
   }
 //returning collider info
 public Box1 getBox1() {
 for (int i =frameCount/600; i >0; i--) {
    return new Box1( block[i].x - Blockpic.width/2, block[i].y-Blockpic.height/2, block[i].x+Blockpic.height/2, block[i].y+Blockpic.height/2);
 }
 }

}



class Block {
   float x, y;
   int speed;

   Block ( float x, float y, int speed) {
   this.x= x;
   this.y= y;
   this.speed = speed;
}

}
```

Thanks alot!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, as you say, is with this method:

```
public Box1 getBox1() {
   for (int i =frameCount/600; i >0; i--) {
      return new Box1( block[i].x - Blockpic.width/2, block[i].y-Blockpic.height/2, block[i].x+Blockpic.height/2, block[i].y+Blockpic.height/2);
   }
}
```

Ignoring for a second that it doesn't make sense to have a return statement inside a for loop like this, the whole problem is that computers are too stupid to know what the value of frameCount is before they run the code. What if frameCount is 0? Or negative?

If frameCount is 0 or negative, then the body of the for loop will never be executed, and this method will never return anything. That's the error.

You might know that frameCount will always be positive, but the computer doesn't.

**Edit: Continuing in response to your below comment:**

If you want help, you have to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Note that this should be as few lines as possible, just to get the basics across. We don't need any collision detection, just a function you call. Here's an example:

```
void setup(){
  String s = getString(true);
  println(s);
}

String getString(boolean b){
  if(b){
    return "testing";
  }
}
```

If you try to run this code, you'll get an error telling you that "This method must return a result of type String".

The reason you get this error is because: what will the getString() function return if I pass in a value of false? It won't return anything! This is exactly like what your code is complaining about. **We** can see that getString() is only ever called with a value of true, but the computer isn't smart enough to figure that out.

You seem to misunderstand the power that a compiler has. It **can't see** what will happen at runtime. Even if it's obvious to you that the boolean will always be true (or in your case, that frameCount is always positive), the compiler **can't know that**. And since it can't know that, it's telling you that you might not return a value from a method with a return type, and that's a compiler error.

You need to refactor your code so that it always returns something from methods that have a return type. However, I'm skeptical that the for loop does what you think it does- but you haven't really explained what you think it does, so that's just a guess.

And the reason you didn't encounter this error in your other methods is because none of them contain this logical error. The only other function that has a return type is this one:

```
boolean isOverlap( Box1 b ) {
   if (lotsOfLogic) {
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Notice how even if the if statement evaluates to false, you still return something from this function. That's what you need to do with your getBox1() function.

Comment: Hi, I guess that makes sense but why would it tell me that the return type is incorrect? Would'nt it be a Nullpointer exception then ? Furthermore following that logic, simply defining the framecount as positive ( i = 0+ frameCount/600) should solve the problem. In addition how come I did not encounter the error in my previous methods? Thank you very much for your answer and your time but sadly this did not get me any closer to actually solving my problem....

Comment: @MariusHumphrey I've edited my post to answer your new questions. If you still aren't clear, please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can work from.

Comment: Hi sorry I was traveling so i couldn't get back to you. Thanks for your help, I now understand what was wrong. I just ended up using a simpler class for the collision. Again thanks for the Help!